# Make MySQL Connector reuse a SSLSessionContextImpl

Tags: java, mysql

Whilst investigating a suspected memory leak in our Java application, we found that much of the memory was being used by instances of `SSLSessionContextImpl` that were being created by the MySQL Connector - one instance per connection.

This became a problem for us, because as of OpenJDK 8u222, each instance of `SSLSessionContextImpl` contains a cache with an initial capacity of `(20480 / 0.75) + 1 = 27307` (see [JDK-8210985](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210985) and [JDK source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ec853359ccc45e41d37a505ec6bebe25a9ee1fdc/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/util/Cache.java#L268)). This, combined with a Hikari connection pool that created ten new connections every half-hour (the default behaviour), meant that after a week we had about 1GB worth of dead `SSLSessionContextImpl` instances. These were in the tenured-generation memory pool, and phantom-referenced by the [`AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread` class](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/a0ca826f5cdf51a98356fdfb1bf251eb042f80bf/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java), and we were seeing our application die due to running out of memory (in a Docker container limited to 1GB), so my guess is that a proper GC could not be performed in time on the instances that had accumulated.

Naively, it seems as if the MySQL connector is not behaving quite right, and that for the same database server, it should be re-using the same `SSLSessionContextImpl` - after all, the [JavaDoc of the `SSLSessionContext` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSessionContext.html) (which it implements) says:

> A `SSLSessionContext` represents a set of `SSLSessions` associated with a single entity. For example,it could be associated with a server or client who participates in many sessions concurrently.

That describes our scenario perfectly! Yet the Connector creates a new `SSLSessionContext` per connection.

So, two questions:

1. Why does the MySQL connector not re-use the `SSLContext`? (Of course we can't read the developers' minds - but are there reasons why one might not want to re-use it?)
2. Can we by some means make it re-use the `SSLContext`?

Comment: We're having a similar situation where memory of a Spring Boot app slowly goes up until GC starts going crazy. Looking at the heap dump we saw hundreds of sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl held in the connectionFinalizerPhantomRefs of the mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer for question one:**

The MariaDB Connector added functionality to create the `SSLContext` every time in [CONJ-670](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-670) (released in 2.4.0, backported to 1.0.8.0). The reasoning was to allow the key store and trust store to dynamically change at runtime.

**Workaround/mitigation**

This doesn't force the `SSLContext` to be re-used - but it does reduce the memory footprint of having lots of them on the heap.

By adding a JVM flag `-Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheSize=0`, the pre-[JDK-8210985](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210985) behaviour is restored.

Setting it to `0` means the cache size is effectively infinite. But in practice, that means it initially allocates a small amount of memory for the cache and allows it to grow indefinitely. Without this, the cache's initial capacity is `27307`, which is rather large!

Comment: Hi, we have a similar problem. I will try to set -Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheSize and -Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheTimeout I found the second JVM property on a different thread. I just wounder how  sessionCacheTimeout corresponfs to http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/security/ssl/SSLSessionContextImpl.html There is no property for sessionCacheTimeout

Comment: That link looks like it's documentation for openjdk 7, which I guess doesn't expose that property?

Comment: sorry, I could only edit this broken comment for 5 Minutes. Here in a more clear form:
we have a similar problem. I will try to set -Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheSize and additionally Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheTimeout. This second JVM property I found on a different thread. I just wounder how the JVM property sessionCacheTimeout corresponds to the class SSLSessionContextImpl. There seems no property for sessionCacheTimeout
http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/security/ssl/SSLSessionContextImpl.html

Comment: Thanx PMah, but even not on https://devdocs.io/openjdk~8/javax/net/ssl/sslsessioncontext

Comment: Sorry, I've not come across that JVM property before. Looking at the code, I can't see it referenced anywhere: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLSessionContextImpl.java

Comment: good to know. google found me that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15743  Maybe I get that in wrong context or they mixed that up with -Djavax.net.ssl.sessionTimeout

Comment: Why should `javax.net.ssl.sessionCacheSize` be set to `0`? That means effectively setting the cache size to infinite, while we're trying to bind it, since it's occupying far too much of the heap. Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: You're right, setting it to `0` means it's effectively infinite. But in practice, that means it initially allocates a small amount of memory for the cache and allows it to grow indefinitely. Without this, the cache's initial capacity is `27307`, which is rather large!